# How to calculate take-off and landing distances for a light plane?

Tags: landing, takeoff, airplane, declared-distances

I cannot find a generic takeoff chart for the 850 lbs BD-5B Micro-plane. How can I find, generate, or calculate the takeoff and landing distances needed? I did find this chart below and included the specifications. Please provide an example I can follow and learn from.
[image]
[image]

Comment: That is definitely not an ultralight!

Comment: @quietflyer what would you call it?

Comment: I'd call it fun!

Comment: @Justintimeforfun At least in the US, an ultralight must be less than 254 lbs. and carry 5 gallons or less of fuel. Since this plane has a gross weight of 850 lbs. and carries 26 gal. of fuel, it can't be an ultralight.

Comment: You need the values of at least thrust, weight wing surface, density and maximum $C_l$, obviously all at takeoff. I think everything is know except max $C_l$ (?)

Comment: @sophit Does this help?

Comment: Yes perfect. Now you can put everything in the last diagram (the one with the "takeoff parameter" - use the second equation for propeller aircraft) of [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/26269) and you should get a good approximation. Obviously you have to use takeoff values, with $C_{l_{TO}}$ being $1.21 \times C_{l_{max}}$. $\sigma$ is the density ratio in respect to ISA sea level.

Comment: Are you planning to bet your life on an answer from ASE ; )