# How to determine thrust and power requirements from take-off ground roll distance?

Tags: takeoff, thrust

I'm working on a project which requires me to determine the power requirements of a propulsion system from a specific take-off distance. Starting with this equation:
$$
    s_g\approx \frac{1.21(W/S)}{g\rho (Cl)_{max}(T/W)}
$$
I rearranged to get
$$
T=\frac{1.21(W^2/S)}{g\rho Cl_{max}s_g}
$$
My question is: Is this the total thrust at takeoff, and if so, is this (following equation) a valid method of determining the power requirements?
$$
P_{req}=\frac{TV_{lo}}{\eta _{prop}}
$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you get that equation?

Comment: @sophit I took it from the textbook "Aircraft Performance and Design" by John D. Anderson

Comment: There's no explanation about how to use it in the book?

Comment: @sophit returning back to the textbook it mentions that T/W in the original equation is evaluated at a velocity of 0.7Vlo (average T/W using average velocity), does this mean its not valid to use the actual lift-off speed? I would like to figure out the absolute max thrust and power required throughout the takeoff and climb

Comment: "quick & dirty" equations like that one normally refer to "nominal" conditions: T is the max thrust available @ all engines operative, W it max takeoff weight and S the nominal wing surface. You plug everything inside and you get the field length or the needed T/W to stay under a certain length. [This answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26265/in-raymer-diagram-take-off-parameter-take-off-distance-what-is-the-differenc) should also help you.

Comment: @sophit perfect! thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome 